# Create Plugin in umbraco11

Tags: plugins, umbraco

Is there any information on how to create a plugin in Umbraco?

I need a properly formatted code or reference to understand how to create the plugin.

I watched a video, but the code is unclear to me.[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61Thxiq0xag&t=3s] Furthermore, I read some articles from Umbraco documentation.
[https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/plugins]

Comment: What type of plugin are you trying to create? The link you found is a very specific feature while I suspect you might be looking for something like this? https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/extending/customize-the-editing-experience